# WPF DataGrid binding to List<Type>

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to bind a WPF `DataGrid` to a `List<ClassName>`.

Below is my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source=FileProcessing}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></DataGrid>
```

Below I am binding the list with database records:

```
FileProcessing =  GetFileProcessingInfo(dtDateStart, dtDateEnd);
```

The `FileProcessing` is defined as a property below:

```
public List<FileProcessing_T> FileProcessing { get; set; }
```

The `GetFileProcessingInfo` Method also returns a `List<FileProcessing_T>` object.

The `FileProcessing` list does get some records from the database but the grid does not bind the data from the list.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: change `List` into `ObservableCollection`, and see if that helps?

Comment: Yes, ObservableCollection is better. Anyway I think that the problem is the type of the elements of the list are not compatible with the grid. Can you post the FileProcessing_T info?

Comment: `FileProcessing` is a property, so looks like it should be `Path`, not `Source`. The source of course should be the object which has the property `FileProcessing`. The source here should be a view-model and implicitly flows down the tree via `DataContext`.

Comment: @Hopeless I back that up. And in case it's not clear, "implicitly" is the key word here - the (inherited) `DataContext` is used as the binding's source ONLY if neither `Source`, `RelativeSource`, nor `ElementName` property is set explicitly.

Comment: @Grx70 I mean the Source can be set implicitly via DataContext, does that make sense? In fact it may not be set but `Binding` will need some source which does not exactly mean the `Source` property.

Comment: @Hopeless I agree with you, I only meant to point out that none of the mentioned properties should be set explicitly in order for it to work "automagically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your databinding.

But your have to implement the `INotfifyPropertyChanged` interface in the class where the `FileProcessing` property is located.
Because in the setter of `FileProcessing` you have to perform the change notification.

```
    public ObservableCollection<FileProcessing_T> FileProcessing 
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileProcessing;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_fileProcessing != value)
            {
                _fileProcessing = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FileProcessing");
            }
        }
    }
    ObservableCollection<FileProcessing_T> _fileProcessing;


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Otherwise the UI control will not know (not be notified) that the bound data has changed.

This will be enough to fix your problem.
It would even work if you continued to use `List<FileProcessing_T>` instead of `ObservableCollection<FileProcessing_T>`, however the `ObservableCollection` also supports change notifications if single elements are added and removed from the collection while `List` does not.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Martin your solution helped me.